# Post form to pop-up and an another page with two differnet submit buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, input, submit

I have a form to insert values in database but before inserting, i want to allow user check results. my client asked me to use pop-up. so there is single form name "dimensions" with two different submit buttons; one says "Save" and other says "Test Results". I need to go on nest page in same window when "save" button is clicked but open a pop-up if user click on "Test Results".

I would like to appreciate any help.

Comment: [What have you got so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Is the idea of the "Test Results" just that it more or less echoes back to the user what would've been saved if they'd clicked "Save"? Should it do so via a request to the web server, or are you talking all client-side?

Comment: on save request to the server....any way thanks a lot, i have found a solution using jquery and ajax. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Real pop-ups are highly discouraged as most people use browsers and/or virus software that get rid of them automatically.  What you should probably do is use a modal javascript dialog.

Going down that route:

A simple thing you can do is have whatever you will pop up in the Test Results on the page already but hidden with css.

When the person clicks "Test Results" you can create a javascript modal dialog box (see jquery Dialog http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog for an example - there are plenty out there).  This should have whatever is already in the database when you set up the page.  Plus just before showing, update the appropriate pieces with the things the user updated.

Doing it this way means you still only have 1 form to deal with as the page never refreshes or navigates away during the test.